# Styling individual child component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a parent `ButtonGroup`component that takes in children like `this.props.children`. The children I'm passing to it is the `btnItem` component that renders out single buttons. We can add as many of these buttons as we want.

```
//ButtonGroup Component

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

//buttonItem component: 

render() {
  return (
    <button disabled={this.props.disabled}>{this.props.caption}</button>
  )
}

//final render
<ButtonGroupComponent>
  <buttonItem caption="Nothing"/>
  <buttonItem caption="Something" disabled={true}/>
  <buttonItem caption="Refresh"/>
</ButtonGroupComponent>
```

[image]

^ This is what I get out of the above code.

What I want to achieve is a way for me style the border radius of the first and last item so that they have a curved border. This would have to be dynamic as this styling will be dependent on how many children `buttonItem` we render.

I should also mention that I'm using styled-components for the css of each button.

Comment: if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use first and last child css pseudo selector here. in your Component write following code.

```
const ButtonGroupComponent= styled.div`
     button:first-child {
         border-top-left-radius: 3px;
         border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
     }
     button:last-child {
         border-top-right-radius: 3px;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
     }
 `;
```

and render function like this

```
<ButtonGroupComponent>
  <buttonItem caption="Nothing"/>
  <buttonItem caption="Something" disabled={true}/>
  <buttonItem caption="Refresh"/>
</ButtonGroupComponent>
```

check out this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/v06o14kv1l)

Comment: I would've thought that would work but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: I make codestandbox demo for you please check it out.

Answer (score -1):

I wrap a quick example here, I didn't test it yet but you could try:

```
const StyledButtonGroupComponent = styled(
     ({ willBeStyled, children, ...rest }) =>(
       <ButtonGroupComponent {...rest}>{children}</ButtonGroupComponent>
    ))`

    ${props => React.Children.toArray(props.children).length <= props.willBeStyled && `
     ...first child, last child styles go here...
    `}

    `
```